# Is this functional dependancy a trivial? (Relational Database Design)

Tags: database, relational

I have this problem:

```
R = (A, B, C, D, E)
```

and

```
F = (A -> BC, B -> CD, E -> AD)
```

the book says that this in BCNF because all FDs are trivial.

My question is: how this FDs is trivial?

Comment: What book are you using ? what page ?

Answer (score 0):

by what you've posted :

> R = ABCDE
>
> 1. A -> BC
> 2. B -> CD
> 3. E -> AD

the candidate key is E

All the left hand side FDs do not show E so this is not a BCNF.
and hence the non trivial FD.